# Where did my screenshots on Windows 10 get stored to?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

I'm using Windows 10 and I have a LogiTech keyboard.  I would like to take a screen shot and the keyboard shortcuts advertised online say to press the Windows key and "Prnt Scr" simultaneously.  After doing this, though, I don't see any screen shots saved to my

```
C:\Users\myuserid\Pictures\Saved Pictures
```

folder.  Not sure if this is because my "Prnt Scr" key is the same key as "Home" or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: When you press the key, if a screenshot is taken, you should receive a notification of that fact which indicates where the screenshot is located

Comment: When pressing Windows+PrtScn do you see a blink in the screen (the way it shows that the screenshot is captured)?

Comment: No I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Then the issue is not the location, but that the screenshot isn't captured for some reason

Comment: Ok.  Let me know what additional information I can provide to help figure out what the solution is.

Comment: It's likely about the Home key, see my answer

Comment: you may also have an fn button that you may need to press.

Comment: Hi @YisroelTech, did you mean to provide an answer to this question or a link?  The only answer I see on this question isn't from you.

Comment: There are two answers down below, one from me (with a screen recording)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They go into `c:\user\your username\Pictures\Screenshots\`.

If you have OneDrive, they'll go into `C:\Users\your username\OneDrive - Company Name\Pictures\Screenshots`

Comment: What is the full path?

Comment: @Dave I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  As a foot note, the shortcut key on my LogiTech keyboard is the Windows Key + Fn + Print Scrn/Home

Comment: Doesn't work for me. After dimming the screen, Print Screen doesn't seem to leave a file ANYWHERE.

Answer (score 2):

The default location for those screenshots is `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots` (e.g. `C:\Users\your_username\Pictures\Screenshots` or `C:\Users\your_userid\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots`).

If you do not see the screenshots there, maybe they aren't captured for some reason, when pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> combination you should see the screen getting darker for a second to show that it captured the screenshot:
[image]

If the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key is together with the <kbd>Home</kbd> you most likely need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> as well. So <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

As an alternative, you can use the newer screenshot utility, with the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut. This one will have a pop-up notification that you can click to see the screenshot (and also see where it was saved).